# A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in for

Tags: php

hi i have a problem please help me

```
for($i=0;$i!=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
{
$play=mysql_result($result,$i);
session_start();
$_SESSION['$movie'] = $play;
?>
<a class="play" href="player.php"><?php print ($play).'</br></br>';}?></a>
```

where is my code is wrong ?

Comment: @Jan Turon you added a close-bracket where there wasn't one, and put it in the wrong place.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe seems like invalid edit - rolling back then

Answer (score 2):

move `session_start()` before your for-cycle

Comment: And move the closing a tag inside the for-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

for($i=0;$i!=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
{
    $play=mysql_result($result,$i);
    $_SESSION['$movie'] = $play;
?>

<a class="play" href="player.php"><?php print ($play).'</br></br>';}?></a>
```

Comment: tnx for your replay but its a search engine
i cant select my choice if i put the session_start() out
but when it's fall in my for it works good but makes error :(

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
for($i=0;$i!=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++){
    $play=mysql_result($result,$i);
    $_SESSION['$movie'] = $play;
    print( '<a class="play" href="player.php">' . $play . '</br></br></a>');
}
?>
```

You have an additional error where your open a tag is repeated, but your closing a tag is outside the for loop.  Your $_SESSION['$movie'] variable is only going to have the final value of $play in it, too - meaning that it's pretty much a waste of processor time to set it over and over and over again.

Comment: tnx 
but still i have a problem
when i click in for example 2 different link i get the same page :(
it means i just can see the last i of for 
plz help

Comment: Well, no matter what, your href on the a tag there is still just `player.php` - there's no id associated with it.  You need to pass a `?id=$play' into there, too ... and then on player.php, you need to be able to interpret that id properly.

Comment: can you write down the exact code of id properly ??
i have not any experiment about it

Comment: @user2367934 It's really one of the more basic elements of PHP - how to read variables from URLs, along with quite a bit of 'how do you do it properly' involving injection attacks and the like.  I'd really recommend [picking up a book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449319262/) that will help teach you the basics, rather than having me go through this in comments trying to (poorly) walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to this : if your file Unicode is : UTF-8 or something like this , you'll see this error by PHP
Set your Unicode to UTF-8 without BOM if you're going to write in other languages

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
...
?>
```

Note the `<?php` instead of `<?` - this did the trick for me, when `session_start()` wasn't working.

Also, you wanna make sure your code is placed on top of the php document.

Answer (score 0):

session_start must be mention on the top of your script and there should not put/write any code before it. like:

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>
// other stuff or page start here
```

----OR ----

You may check your page, in which you have already started session.